# Почему «по приезду» нелегитимно

Tags: склонение, грамматика

Почему некоторые существительные можно ставить в предложный падеж, используя окончания `-у` / `-ю` («в лесу», «в строю»), но выражение «по приезд**у**» является неверным (нужно писать «по приезд**е**»)?

Comment: ***Падежь*** тоже неверно.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

«По приезд**у**» (дательный падеж) — «легитимно», но только в значениях, не связанных с приданием предлогу «по» значения «после», и не требующих для этого предложного падежа с его окончанием.

Предложный падеж позволяет через свойственную ему статичность обозначить как бы место во времени («где» на оси времени) — указанием момента окончания действия, выраженного отглагольным существительным (здесь — «приезд»). Этим организуется обстоятельство времени для другого действия.

Дательный же падеж выражает применение такого «другого действия» к самому обозначенному действию (приезду). Ниже — абстрактный пример.

> По приезд**у** наших потенциальных партнёров (или прилету инопланетян), ожидаемому *через неделю*, *сегодня* состоится заседание подготовительного комитета.
>
> По их приезд**е** станет ясно, удались ли подготовительные мероприятия и не нанес ли по их приезд**у** удар наш конкурент своими интригами.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что "в лесу" и "в строю" – это т.наз. местный падеж, а слово "приезд" никак в местном падеже стоять не может. "По приезду" – это попытка использовать дательный падеж, а требуется предложный.

Answer (score 2):

http://gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_120

В значении «после чего-н.» предлог *по* употребляется в предложном п.:
по завершении (= после завершения),
по истечении (= после истечения),
по окончании (= после окончания),
по предъявлении документа (= после предъявления),
по прибытии (= после прибытия),
по приезде (= после приезда),
по возвращении (= после возвращения),
по прилёте (= после прилёта).

Ср.: предлог по употребляется с дат. п. при указании на поверхность или пределы, где что-н. совершается: идти по обочине, поставить всё по местам, ударить по руке.

Answer (score 1):

Правильный вариант: по приезде.

Здесь предлог ПО участвует в управлении предложным, а не дательным падежом. Принципиальное различие этих падежей заключается в том, что Д.п. – направленный , а П.п. – ненаправленный падеж.

В данном случае используется обстоятельственная разновидность П.п. со значением  определенного периода времени (по приезде - это после приезда). Падежи различаются и по вопросу: когда – П.п. и по чему (в соответствии с чем) – Д.п. **Предложный падеж обязателен, так как он исключает ненужную направленность дательного падежа.** Например: По приезду именитых особ можно было судить о том, что вечер уже в разгаре (по чему? направленный Д.п.).

В настоящее время предлог ПО все реже используется для образования П.п., например: скучать по вас. Раньше говорили также "скучать по городе".

Comment: А по городе скучали где?

Comment: Раньше с существительными употреблялись оба падежа, что отражено и в классической литературе:  "Дядя часто скучал по губернском городе" (Решетников Ф.М., 19 век). "Да, признаться, и соскучился по Ермаке Тимофеиче" (А. К. Толстой).

Comment: Когда я приезжаю в деревню, там многие и сейчас скучают по городе. Видимо они просто более консервативны))).

Answer (score -3):

Мне видится так, что мы сами себя запутали. Забыли корни русского языка. Мы стали исключения и местный говор принимать за норму. Потому возникает путаница и попытки "натянуть" неграмотную речь на существующие правила.
Почему мы перестали говорить "д'омы" и используем вместо этого "дом' а"? 
Почему мы говорим "директор'а" вместо "дир'екторы"?

Теперь о "приезде".
Возьмём слово ЛЕС. В предложном падеже оно имеет две формы в зависимости от предлога. В лесу, о лесе, по лесу,  при лесе (чтобы не ошибиться уточню: скучать по лесу).

Возможно, что с "приездом" та же картина. О приезде, но по приезду. Оба варианта - предложный падеж.